# Playing an alert if a script has an error

Tags: bash, alert

I run various scripts inside BASH. These use various programs, but mostly for compiling. E.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp file1.txt file2.txt
pdflatex file.txt
bibtex file
pdflatex file.txt
```

Sometimes, a program runs into an error, which it prints out and stops the script from finishing. Is there any way to have the BASH script trigger a bell, notifying me that an error has been found and the script has stopped?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `trap` command to define an exit function and notify you:

```
function exit_shell {
    echo -e "Goodbye!\a"
}
trap exit_shell 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 11 12 13 14 15

# And the rest of your script goes here...
```

This way, almost any signal (except for `9` or `KILL` which can't be trapped) will cause your function to execute. The `\a` will sound the terminal bell in a hardware independent manner (although it's almost always ASCII 0x07).

However, why limit yourself to a mere bell which might not sound. You could send yourself an SMS text using the `mail` command and your cell phone service provider's email gateway. For example, in Verizon you can send an email to *phone@vtext.com* where *phone* is your phone number without dashes.

```
function exit_shell {
    echo -e "Goodbye!" | mailx -s "Command failed!" $phone@vtext.com
}
trap exit_shell 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Or, you can find a [command line Twitter client](https://github.com/jgoerzen/twidge/wiki) or [Facebook client](http://fbcmd.dtompkins.com/) and update all of your friends with your status.

Answer (score 3):

`echo -e "\007"`

007 is ASCII for BEL or bell.

this system beep?

Comment: This is awesome! Two thumbs up :)

Answer (score 1):

Other than the terminal bell in cctan's answer (which can be disabled), there is no universal way to do this. In Linux, the "aplay" command can be used to play a sound file from the command line.