# Bash play sound on first error

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that runs a bunch of various commands.  It takes a while to run and I would like an audible cue if any of the commands fail, so I can be doing something else but still know as soon as a failure has occurred.  Is there a way to play a sound the first time a command fails?

Two related Stack Overflow questions:

1. By using `set -e`, it's possible to [make a bash script *exit* on the first error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474526/stop-on-first-error).  This is what I'm currently using as it's a very clean mechanism - no need to check error codes on each command.  If there's a way to use this with the equivalent of a "finally" block where I can specify what should happen before exit, that would work.
2. A beep noise apparently can be played by [echoing an ASCII code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833726/playing-an-alert-if-a-script-has-an-error), so even if I'm just able to make one of these simple calls on first error.

Side note: I really am after a simple sound - no need to SMS/tweet/post to Instagram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`help trap` tells us that "A SIGNAL_SPEC of ERR means to execute ARG each time a command's failure would cause the shell to exit when the -e option is enabled.":

```
#!/bin/bash

exit_with_bells() {
    printf '\a'           # Ring terminal bell
    mplayer ~/"some.mp3"  # Play an audio file
    exit 1                # Exit with error
}

trap 'exit_with_bells' ERR

set -e
your commands here
```